# How can i stop a thread running in my Dialog Class from my mainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

My mainwindow looks like this

[image]

it is a qlistwidget with some Job items, whenever any job item is clicked , it shows up the QDialogbox which looks like this.

[image]

The QDialog has a listwidget and a show button, whenever the show button is clicked , a list of 10000 possible employees will show up in the Qlistwidget and these employees are calculated by this function which is in a thread3.

```
    void KeyComd::Print_Descendants_key(IUIAutomation* pUIAutomation, IUIAutomationElement* pParent, int indent)
{
    ///Function which appends 1000 list-items in a QListWidget called "elements_listwidget" in my QDialog.
}
```

The usual flow is:

1. i click an item(Carwash job) in Mainwindow
2. the QDialog box shows-up,i press showbutton and list of 10000 possible employees show up
3. i select an employee jack in QDialog and click okay.
4. the Mainwindow item gets changed to "Car washing job assigned to: Jack, height 5'10, weight 86"

### My question is that in step-3 , even when entire 10000 elements are not loaded yet and i find my preferred employee in first 500  list items, i select it and click 'ok' on dialog box , the item in mainwindow still doesnt change until the thread3 finishes running, can i force stop or terminate thread3 ?? such that when i click okay thread3  stops, and the item in main window changes.

This is my Dialog cpp file named Keycomd.cpp

```
#include "KeyComd.h"
#include "ui_KeyComd.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <vector> 
#include<QDebug>
#include "ExecutionContext.h"
#include "XMLParser.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "BlockCommand.h"
#include "UIAElementUtils.h"

ExecutionContext exc;
QStringList refreshed_elements;

KeyComd::KeyComd(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    HRESULT hr = exc.init();    
}

KeyComd::~KeyComd()
{
}
void KeyComd::on_showbutton_clicked()
{
    ui.elements_listwidget->clear();
    desktop_elements.clear();

    std::thread thread3(&KeyComd::Print_step, this); // Here it calls a thread, because of this thread ,the execution of "Print_Descendants_key" function happens in a separate thread from main thread
    thread3.detach();
}

void KeyComd::Print_step()
{
    Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0);
}

void KeyComd::Print_Descendants_key(IUIAutomation* pUIAutomation, IUIAutomationElement* pParent, int indent)
{
    ///Function which appends 10000 list-items in a QListWidget called "elements_listwidget" in my QDialog.
}
```

my mainwindow.cpp code is

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "XMLParser.h"
#include "ExecutionContext.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "BlockCommand.h"
#include "UIAElementUtils.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <sstream>
#include <QtWidgets/qmessagebox.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qlistwidget.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include "Header.h"
#include <map>
#include <QtWidgets/qinputdialog.h>
#include <vector> 
#include "dragsupport.h"
#include "KeyComd.h"


ExecutionContext exContext;

using namespace std; 

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    populatemaps();
    ui->setupUi(this);
 
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, NULL);
    ExecutionContext exContext;
    hr = exContext.init();
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_xml_scripts_textbox_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
        KeyComd keyComd;
        keyComd.exec();

        if (keyComd.result() == QDialog::Accepted) //when i click okay,the code inside this block gets executed
        {                   
           // Here when okay is clicked, i want to check if thread3 is still running and if it is then stop/terminate the thread3 which is in KeyComd.cpp file 
           
           ui->qlistwidget->additem("Car washing Job assigned to: Jack , height 5'10, weight 86, age 21");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `QThread` in your main window, then move the `QDialog` object to that new thread. Attach the `accepted` signal on your `QDialog` object to the `quit` slot in the `QThread` object, that will close the thread. I've added the code below with the changes.

Main window

```
#include <QThread>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "XMLParser.h"
#include "ExecutionContext.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "BlockCommand.h"
#include "UIAElementUtils.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <sstream>
#include <QtWidgets/qmessagebox.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qlistwidget.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include "Header.h"
#include <map>
#include <QtWidgets/qinputdialog.h>
#include <vector> 
#include "dragsupport.h"
#include "KeyComd.h"


ExecutionContext exContext;

using namespace std; 

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    populatemaps();
    ui->setupUi(this);
 
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, NULL);
    ExecutionContext exContext;
    hr = exContext.init();
 // QThread dialog_thread; move this to header
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_xml_scripts_textbox_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
        KeyComd keyComd;
        keyComd.moveToThread(&dialog_thread);
        connect(&keyComd, &QDialog::Accepted, &dialog_thread, &QThread::quit);
        dialog_thread.start();
        keyComd.exec();        
        
        if (keyComd.result() == QDialog::Accepted) //when i click okay,the code inside this block gets executed
        {                   
           // Here when okay is clicked, i want to check if thread3 is still running and if it is then stop/terminate the thread3 which is in KeyComd.cpp file 
           ui->qlistwidget->additem("Car washing Job assigned to: Jack , height 5'10, weight 86, age 21");   
           emit keyComd.accepted();
        }
}
```

Dialog Box

```
#include "KeyComd.h"
#include "ui_KeyComd.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <vector> 
#include<QDebug>
#include "ExecutionContext.h"
#include "XMLParser.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "BlockCommand.h"
#include "UIAElementUtils.h"

ExecutionContext exc;
QStringList refreshed_elements;

KeyComd::KeyComd(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    HRESULT hr = exc.init();
}

KeyComd::~KeyComd()
{
}
void KeyComd::on_showbutton_clicked()
{
    ui.elements_listwidget->clear();
    desktop_elements.clear();
    this->Print_Descendants_key();
}

void KeyComd::Print_step()
{
    Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0);
}

void KeyComd::Print_Descendants_key(IUIAutomation* pUIAutomation, IUIAutomationElement* pParent, int indent)
{
    ///Function which appends 10000 list-items in a QListWidget called "elements_listwidget" in my QDialog.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i got an idea what you are saying, but i am getting an error in this line         `keyComd.moveToThread(&dialog_thread);`  saying identifier dialog_thread is undefined. in the mainwindow class.

Comment: You need to make sure you're adding a `QThread` object named `dialog_thread` (or whatever you want to call it obviously as long as all the references to it are also using the same name) to your class declaration/ `mainwindow.h` file. The reason you're getting the error is because it doesn't exist until you specify it does in the header/declaration. It's not a member that can be accessed in other methods if you don't have it there. I added it to the constructor but forgot comment that you need to remember to move it to the header otherwise it won't exist. I've updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i declared it in the header, its running without showing any errors, but  actually i am not able to get desired behavior, the desired behavior is the elements in the Dialog's listwidget  keep loading in front of the end user real-time, that is the reason i decided to keep that function in a separate thread.                                                                                                   but when i try the code tactic you showed the dialog screen freezez and remains unresponsive until all of the elements are loaded in the dialogs qlistwidget.

Comment: The behavior which happens when i follow the code in my original post was that the elements were loading in front of the user realtime, i guess its because i did the detaching thing     thread3.detach();
is there any way i can do a similar kind of thing in your code ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question/what you're trying to do. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Sure, when i click show button in my QDialog i want this function to run    

 Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0);  
, what this function does is load a list of around 10,000 elements in the qlistwidget present in my QDialog. 
when i didnt have any thread in my code then i was getting this behaviour, as soon as i click showbutton, entire UI was fronzen , because Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0) function started execution

Comment: and the UI only responsive only after all the 10000 values are calculated by that function. and all values show up all at once in the QListwidget.  so for this reason i decided that execution of  Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0); should happen in a separate thread such that the UI does not get frozen.

Comment: with the code you provided i guess that Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0); this function is being executed in a separate thread but still upon clicking the show button the UI gets frozen and becomes responsive only after all 10,000 elements are added all at once in the qlistwidget.